# Docker and node:alpine image size

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux, dockerhub

this is more a question than troubleshooting. I have noticed that the image size of my node:alpine containers is bigger than advertised on DockerHub. Attached raw images size in both Docker Hub and Docker Desktop. Is this expected? Due to being on a Mac OS or am I missing something?  [image: Docker Desktop Screenshot]

[image: DockerHub Screenshot]

Comment: The docker hub column text is 'compressed size'. I assume that the size we see locally is uncompressed.

Comment: DUH! :facepalm: That's what I wass missing :D